# FCBF method for feature selection

Tags: python, filter

i want to use Fast correlation based filter (FCBF) selection method to select the significant and non redundant variables among independent variables for classification . I found a python implementation of the method in github https://github.com/shiralkarprashant/FCBF.
i followed the same steps to use the method but i got the following error :

```
C:\Users\HP> python fcbf.py -h
(null): can't open file 'fcbf.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

C:\Users\HP>cd C:\Users\HP\Downloads\FCBF-master\FCBF-master\src

C:\Users\HP\Downloads\FCBF-master\FCBF-master\src> python fcbf.py -h
  File "fcbf.py", line 158
    print "Using minimum SU value as default threshold: {0}".format(thresh)
                                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```